# Any Ajax or Flash slider which displays websites/url aside from images

Tags: jquery, ajax, flash, iframe, slider

Hi there guys I was wondering if you have any suggestions on any flash or ajax slider (plugin/library) which can display websites instead of images with features like transition effects animation and infinite looping.

I am currently playing with anythingslider a jquery plugin but couldn't get to display url's/websites with it.

Also Id like to know if you guys know if there are any alternatives to anythingslider.  Any flash or ajax plugin will do as long as it has the features i mentioned above.

I know that what i want can be achieved using iframe and javascript which accepts a list of urls and then loops through the list displaying websites instead of images.  But im looking for a more flexible and flashy way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out 30 great sliders here.. http://www.themeflash.com/30-stunning-jquery-slider-plugins-and-tutorials-to-boost-your-work/

Honestly I doubt anyone can tell you which one is the best as you would be the only person who can determine which one works best for "you"

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eddy :) but i was looking for something that can display webpages instead of images.

Comment: @royjavelosa: That's why I suggested that you have to use some of those plugins to understand how it works. Most of the sliders aren't just for images. They can display any html data. So all you basically have to do is insert the code for iframe. Using jquery to loop through the list of urls shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: @Eddy: I did look at your list.  Also I already encountered some of them during my google searching, and tested some of them even before i posted this question here, that is why was strongly considering anythingslider.  My inquiry was are there any specific plugin you might know or recommend which can display an actual website e.g. google->yahoo->bing and so on.  Id appreciate if you can recommend something which you had actually used which really stoodout among the other options. Thanks.

Comment: @royjavelosa: My favorite one is http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/ ... I put together a quick example for you. You will need to fix a few things here and there such as css etc but it gives you an idea on how to do this.. http://jsfiddle.net/zSrrW/

Comment: @Adil: Thank you so much exactly what I was looking for!!!  Easy to use flexible and with all the features in my wish list :)  Also thank you for the example it was very helpful.  Just one last question, I already know how to set it to scroll automatically but is it possible to remove the control buttons (back and next arrow buttons) Again thanks!!!

Comment: @royjavelosa: You welcome. It's possible. You have to use the following configuration.. `buttonNextHTML: null, buttonPrevHTML: null` ..for an example check out http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_controls.html